# With XSLT's format-time(), how to specify if dots are used in am/pm markers?

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, saxon

Say you have `format-time(current-time(), '[P]')`:

- [Saxon](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/) will show `a.m.` or `p.m.`
- If you use `[PN]`, Saxon shows `A.M.` or `P.M.`

Is it possible to get `am` or `pm`, as in the [examples of the XSLT 2.0 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#date-time-examples)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A min/max width can be specified in the format [picture string](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#date-picture-string), with the format `min-max`. Limiting the length to 2 produces the expected result with Saxon, e.g.:

```
format-time(current-time(), '[P,2-2]')
```

Comment: There are some other subtleties as well. For example setting language to en-US uses "a.m" and "p.m" for 12 noon and midnight (or is it the other way around, I forget), whereas lang=en-GB gives you "noon" and "midnight". Which won't suit everyone, of course, but that's the way of these things.

Comment: Awesome, thank you for this precision—this feature has more horsepower under its hood than one could think at first sight.